# TextureAtlas issue get Texture

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a texture atlas and I want to get a specific texture in it by name, but I get all textureAtlas with all texture.

Why?

This is the code:

```
this.textureLeft= textureAtlas.findRegion(textureLeftName).getTexture();
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Your leftTexture has to be a TextureRegion and not Texture.

TextureRegion tr = atlas.findTextureRegion(region);

Just like that.

getTexture() returns original texture that regions is cut out. So you dont want that.